# Vertically align text in contenteditable div in td where the div is same size as td

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a td with a div with some text. The div shall have 100% of the height and width of the td, and the text shall be centered both vertically and horizontally. I sometimes want to format the text in the div using spans, and it can happen that the text is too long so it will be in multiple lines.

I tried using a flexbox, but that made the text make line breaks whenever there was a span. Also tried to put the div in a div, and only use the flexbox on the parent div, but that also didn't work. I've also tried to set the div to "display: table-cell", but this made the div not able to fill the entire cell. So now I really don't know what to try.

Table cell:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 16pt;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Div with text in the cell:

```
.cellText {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Please see why and how to make: [mre] and : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines of code to your `.cellText` CSS class:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Then add a `div` element inside your `.cellText` instances and put your text content there.

### Example

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 16pt;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.cellText {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


/* For testing purposes */
td {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:350px">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cellText">
        <div>
          <span>First span</span> <span>Second span</span> <span>Third span</span> <span>Fourth span</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cellText">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cellText">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum commodo, purus ac vestibulum dapibus.
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cellText">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As soon as I set the inner div to be editable, it sets the size of it to the size of the text: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltgc0usn/. If I cellText to be editable it works. But when I then delete all text the inner div is removed, and when I then insert spans next time, it will not look right: https://jsfiddle.net/32sqdboj/